# To find number of roots of complex polynomial provided degree of it.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ are two complex non-constant polynomials of degree $m,n$ respectively. The number of roots of $P(z)=P(z)Q(z)$ counted with multiplicity is equal to
>
> 1. ) $\min\{m,n\}$
> 2. ) $\max\{m,n\}$
> 3. ) $m+n$
> 4. ) $m-n$.

I think Rouche's theorem will be helpful to find zeros of $P(z)=P(z)·Q(z)$

But I am not getting how to proceed.

Comment: What is the degree of PQ?

Comment: Well, never mind. The problem has been ruined for you.

Comment: Deg(PQ)=m+n . So no of zeros will be m+n.

Comment: @Mariano Suarez probably you are right

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The degree of the polynomial $H(z) = P(z)Q(z)$ is given by the sum of the degree of $P$ and the degree of $Q$ and hence $m+n$. Since we are counting repeated roots separately, the number of roots counted with multiplicity is then also given by $m+n$. So the answer is $(3)$

Comment: But why it is given P=PQ? The L H.S is not other function H it is P=PQ.

Comment: @Kavita I was referring generally, however when you take $H(z) = P(z)$, the argument still holds.

Comment: Ok thanks for that explanation. I just kept myself confused for that reason.